# Cómo limitar una array fórmula hasta la última fila con datos, en Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy haciendo una Webapp y recojo los datos de un formulario, los escribo en un Sheets y ahí los proceso con una array fórmula.
El problema es que se aumenta una fila al final de la hoja, en vez de escribirse en la primera fila vacía.
Puedo eliminar todas la filas vacías, pero necesito otra forma de hacerlo sin tener que eliminar las filas.
Agrego el código de una versión muy simplificada de la Webapp:

```
//G.S.
function doGet () {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();};
function escribir (array){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,1,array[0].length).setValues(array);};
```

index HTML

```
<body> 
    <input type="number" id="numero1" value="">
    <input type="number" id="numero2" value="">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="boton">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        btn.addEventListener('click',escribirPartida)
        function escribirPartida() {
           array = [[numero1.value, numero2.value]]
           console.log(array)
           google.script.run.escribir(array)}
    </script>  
  </body>
```

Este es el resultado, en vez de escribirse los datos en la fila amarilla se escriben al final de la hoja.

[image: datos se escriben al final de la hoja y no en la primera fila vacía]

Traté de poner una condición en la función array para dejar vacías todas la celdas que hay abajo. Esta es la función array: `=ArrayFormula(SI(A2:A+B2:B =0;"";A2:A+B2:B))`

Necesito una forma de limitar la ArrayFormula para que no se escriban los datos al final.
(yo sé que se puede hacer desde el Script, pero necesito hacerlo desde el sheets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo causa el uso de uso de referencias abiertas como `A2:A` en conjunto con tener filas vacías. Para no tener que eliminar las filas vacías, podrías modificar tu fórmula para limitar el número de filas que esta devuelve. Una forma de hacerlo es usando `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` en conjunto con una forma de contar las filas requeridas. Ejemplo:

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SI(A2:A+B2:B =0;"";A2:A+B2:B);COUNT(A2:A);1))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Solo quiero agregar que tuve que cambiar las comas por puntos y comas; espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: @ZCH Gracias por la observación (respuesta corregida)